# Why is the args array always initialized to an empty array?

Tags: java, jvm

Here is the java code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(args.length); // the result is always 0, NPE occurred not possible
}
```

Why is the `args` array always initialized to an empty array? is there any case to make the args null, other than to call `main(null)` in another `main`?

I want to know if there are any non-programmatic ways to cause this problem, like some settings.

Comment: Do you understand what the `args` parameter represents?

Comment: args is whatever args you pass to the java program, your command line arguments. I personally think it would be more correct to have "no arguments" or an empty array, rather than null

Comment: Of course, there are “non-programmatic ways”, as that’s referring to infinite possibilities. You can hack the JVM, for example. Or use a debugger to stop before the statement and change the variable to `null`. But what does this information gain you? Which actual problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java when you pass arguments on the command line to the program those arguments are passed within the `args` array.  For example:

```
> java MyProgram arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
```

To read those args you'd do this:

```
class MyProgram {
   public static final main( String[] args ) {
       for( int i = 0; i < args.length; i++ ) {
          System.out.println( args[i] );
       }
   }
}
```

Now if `args` could be null then I'd have to add yet more code to prevent it from throwing an NPE by adding an `if( args == null )`.  Messy.  But if `args` is always guarateed to be non-null then I can safely do what I just did above.

If your main method is invoked through the java program `args` will not be null.  So normal execution it won't be null.  However, if some other code tries to invoke `MyProgram.main( null )` obviously it will be null and `MyProgram` will throw an NPE.  Therefore, it's best to do `MyProgram.main( new String[0] )` and it won't throw the NPE.